# What does the web part property RSS Feed Limit do?

Tags: 2013, web-part, rss

I'm trying out the OOTB RSS Web Part. My question is simple: What does the RSS Feed Limit web part property do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS Feed Limit will limit the number of items display in the web part.

Let's say if you want to display 1st 10 items from the feed into web part then you need to set that property to 10.

By default, limits RSS feeds to 5 items.

Answer (score 2):

> In the Item Limit section, you can limit the number of items and days to include in an RSS feed.

from https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Manage-RSS-feeds-08a3ed69-1883-42c2-af56-4493bc13912a